# Connect to Oracle Database in Navicat with Thin Client Information

Tags: java, oracle, navicat

I have been given the Oracle JDBC thin client connection string information, but I am not able to use it in Navicat. Here is what I have:

```
#ds.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://my.url.com:3000/EFGH1,cn=OracleContext,dc=bh,dc=url2,dc=net
#ds.username=my_username
#ds.password=my_secure_password
```

Here is the picture of the Navicat information required:
[image: Navicat - Oracle Connection Information]

I've tried nearly every combination of variables and I've search the web quite a bit, but I cannot find any clear idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to "[JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/toc.htm)" for more details on LDAP syntax. I have pasted the code snippet here.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://ldap1.example.com:3500/cn=salesdept,cn=OracleContext,dc=com/salesdb " +
"ldap://ldap2.example.com:3500/cn=salesdept,cn=OracleContext,dc=com/salesdb " +
"ldap://ldap3.example.com:3500/cn=salesdept,cn=OracleContext,dc=com/salesdb";
prop.put("oracle.net.ldap_loadbalance", "OFF" );
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL(url);
ods.setConnectionProperties(prop);
```